# Logical 'OR' condition doesn't work with classes

Tags: swift, logical-operators

I am learning Swift,

Say I have declared two instances of a class:

```
var instanceOne : SomeClass
var instanceTwo : SomeClass
```

In another function, I want to use if condition to check if either one of the instances is not nil, then do something:

```
if !instanceOne || !instanceTwo {
    //Do something
}
```

But I get the compiler error:

`Binary operator '||' cannot be applied to two Bool operands.`

Why this error? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to check whether these classes are not instantiated?? If so use this:

```
var instanceOne : SomeClass?
var instanceTwo : SomeClass?

if instanceOne == nil || instanceTwo == nil {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Note that the variables can't be nil if they're not optional!

Comment: Now I got error 'Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments.'

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Comment: The compiler would have been moaning about the '==' if the variables were not optional.